# WinActivate opens but does not activate the window when window is minimized

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I'm using WinActivate but I'm having problems with the macro stalling when I have the window minimized before I run the macro. The macro will continue if I manually perform the next step in the macro. The macro runs normally if the window is not minimized before I start the macro. I noticed that if the macro starts out minimized, WinActivate will bring up the window but the window will not be active. I have tried WinRestore but it doesn't work. I have tried to have the macro click on the window after WinActivate but the window does not become active and stalls until I manually complete the next step.

Comment: What Info shows Window Spy at the moment you restore the window? Which window gets active in this case?

Comment: I downloaded Window Spy (https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=28220). Do I drag the Window Spy on the window that pops up after WinActivate?

Comment: Window Spy is included with AutoHotkey. Launch it manually from the script's tray-icon menu or the Start Menu before starting the script and look at the moment the window is restored which window gets active instead of the desired one.